# Mixing of static and dynamic pages in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hta

I'm trying to mix static and dynamic content in a CodeIgniter 3.1 tailored website. I'm using the tutorial example given for the static content:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

I'm afraid this would be quite messy for the purpose, since (:any) is too generic and I don't want to use something like `"/static/(:any)"` route.

Any suggestions on how to achieve a solution that let me have a static and controller named friendly URL?

Every idea is welcome and very much appreciated.

---

As my question seems to be difficult to understand, I'll try to ask it once again:

Is there a way to combine static content with the above code (from codeigniter tutorial) and the usual approach  `http://example.com/controller/index_named_method`  dynamic content handling?

Can you give an example?

Should I change `$route['(:any)']` for every static webpage's name i.e.: 
`$route['(home|contact|links)']` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read and understand the rest of the tutorial? Not trying to be a wiseguy but the remaining tutorial parts talk about dynamic content. That said, I don't use the static pages concept presented. Instead, I simply use the the straight forward `http://example.com/[controller-class]/[controller-method]/[arguments]` for all pages. Doing so eliminates having to define a bunch of routes.

Comment: Sure, you're completely right and that's my approach also, but what happen if you want to just use index as a method for keeping http://example.com/[controller-class]/ in the sake of keeping a uniform, elegant, friendly urls site?
You can't, can you?

Comment: If I understand your question, yes. The route `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';` would map the controller Home.php to `http://example.com`. Home.php would need an index method. That's the only route you really need. Any other request to `http://example.com/some_controller` will call the index function of `some_controller`. So, obviously you need to define `index()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I must say that I got to an answer myself; as said in my previous post editing, mixing static and dynamic content using `index()` method in your Controller taking advantage of the tutorial example can be accomplished adding a route with all your controllers name like this:

`$route['(books|flowers|links)'] = '$1';`

Thanks to those who helped.